Using boto3.client in fastapi project
class S3Service:
    """
    A helper class for interacting with AWS S3.

    Parameters
    ----------
    `aws_access_key_id (str)`: 
        AWS access key ID.
    `aws_secret_access_key (str)`: 
        AWS secret access key.
    """

    def __init__(self, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key):
        self.aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id
        self.aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key
        self.client = self._create_s3_client()
    
    def _create_s3_client(self):
        return boto3.client('s3',
                            aws_access_key_id=self.aws_access_key_id,
                            aws_secret_access_key=self.aws_secret_access_key)

    def _handle_info_response(self, response: dict) -> bool:
        status_code = response.get(
            "ResponseMetadata", {}).get("HTTPStatusCode", 0)
        return status_code in [200, 204]

    def upload_fileobj(self, bucket, key, data):
        file_upload_response = self.client.put_object(
            Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=data)
        return self._handle_info_response(
            file_upload_response,
            f"File uploaded path: https://{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/{key}",
            "File upload failed."
        )

When I initialize this class in a FastAPI project, each user will use the same S3Service instance. Since I want to isolate users from each other, I am concerned about the possibility of responses from different users interfering with each other. Could such a situation occur? What would be the correct approach? Should I initialize a new instance for each user? Would using different instances for each user cause performance issues?

Isolating users from each other would be helpful, if you, for example, store specific metadata for each user in your S3Service, or if your users provided their own aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key, but, as I understand, you are using your own s3 account each time, and don’t store any specific metadata in your S3Service for each user, so I couldn't see, why you would need such isolation.
Could you provide more details, why do you want to isolate S3Services?

For example, I will prepare an upload-image endpoint. I'm worried about confusion when multiple users request this endpoint at the same time. Or I'm worried that transactions may slow down when they perform transactions through the same s3Service instance.
So, wouldn't it cause any problems to provide a single s3Service instance to all users and have them perform all S3 operations through this instance?

Ohh I see. Yes, your current realisation may slow down when they perform transactions through the same s3Service instance, because you initialise boto3.client in your__init__. In current realisation you might really need to create a new S3Service. But this approach could be still slow, because at each request you will establish a new connection with S3, that could take some time. If you want to make it as fast as possible I would suggest to use aioboto3 and aioboto3.Session, there would be only 1 connection. Nevertheless, solution with new S3Service still very valid and could fit perfectly
